# Get n number of documents from a collection using MongoDB/MongoEngine

Tags: python, mongodb, mongoengine

Hi everyone I have a document inside a collection like this. (Ignore the absurdity of the question).

```
[
    {
        "tag": "english",
        "difficulty": "hard",
        "question": "What are alphabets",
        "option_1": "98 billion light years",
        "option_2": "23.3 trillion light years",
        "option_3": "6 minutes",
        "option_4": "It is still unknown",
        "correct_answer": "option_1",
        "id": "5f80befbaaf3c9ce2f4e2fb9"
    }
]
```

There are multiple documents such as this one (10000).

I'm trying to write a python get to function using `flask-restful` to get `n` number of documents from this collection.
Currently, I'm confused about how to write a MongoEngine query.

This is what I do to get a single document based on it.

```
def get(self,id):
        questions = Question.objects.get(id=id).to_json()
        return Response(questions,
                    mimetype="application/json",
                    status = 200)
```

for `n` number of documents, I'm unable to figure out what to write inside.

```
    def get_n_questions(self,n):
        body = request.get_json(force =True)
        questions = ???
        return Response(questions,
                    mimetype="application/json",
                    status = 200)
```

Comment: why you don't use `filter` instead of `get`?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `limit(n)` method ([doc](https://docs.mongoengine.org/guide/querying.html#limiting-and-skipping-results)) on a queryset. This will let you retrieve the n firsts documents from the collection.

In your case that would mean:

```
questions = Question.objects().limit(n).to_json()
```

You may also be interested in the `skip(n)` method, this will allow you to do pagination (similarly to a limit/offset from MySQL for instance).